# Raspberry-Pi morse-code LED

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, morse-code

I am new to programming, python and raspberry-pi, but I am keen to learn more. After doing a few basic tutorials I though it might be best to give it a shot and just come up with a task in which I could practice my current skills. 
I prepared a csv file with morse-code and wrote a little script to access the csv and translate it into a blinking LED.
It works! Now I would like to learn a bit more and improve my code. How would a simpler/faster/neater solution look like?

I would appreciate any kind of constructive criticism. (I made a few comments for myself. I hope it is not too annoying)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import csv

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

#cleaning out the csv

with open('Morse.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    letters = [] #a new list with letters only
    codes = [] #a new list with morse code only

    next(readCSV) #jump over the column description line and an empty line
    next(readCSV)

    for row in readCSV: #fill up the new lists

        letter = row[0]
        code = row

        code.remove(row[0]) 

        letters.append(letter) #append letters only
        codes.append(code) #append everything but letters

LetterInput = input('what do you want to morse? ')

MorseCode = [] #a new list where the final code for the LED input is saved

for SingLetter in LetterInput: #iterate through the input

    SingLetUp = SingLetter.upper() #capitalize letters so they can be found in csv

    if SingLetUp not in letters: #jump over spaces and special characters 
        continue

    MorseDex = letters.index(SingLetUp) #find code that corresponds with letter by matching indices 
    SingCode = codes[MorseDex]
    MorseCode.append(SingCode) #fill up list


#iterate through list in list to seperate single words

for pos in MorseCode: 
    for sing in pos:
        print(sing)

        x = 'short'
        y = 'long'
        z = 'none'

#LED blinks while parsing through the list

        if sing == x:
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

        if sing == y:
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

        if sing == z:
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(1)


GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

And here is the csv file

```
letter,position 1,position 2,position 3,position 4,position 5
,,,,,
A,short,long,none,none,none
B,long,short,short,short,none
C,long,short,long,short,none
D,long,short,short,none,none
E,short,none,none,none,none
F,short,short,long,short,none
G,long,long,short,none,none
H,short,short,short,short,none
I,short,short,none,none,none
J,short,long,long,long,none
K,long,short,long,none,none
L,short,long,short,short,none
M,long,long,none,none,none
N,long,short,none,none,none
O,long,long,long,none,none
P,short,long,long,short,none
Q,long,long,short,long,none
R,short,long,short,none,none
S,short,short,short,none,none
T,long,none,none,none,none
U,short,short,long,none,none
V,short,short,short,long,none
W,short,long,long,none,none
X,long,short,short,long,none
Y,long,short,long,long,none
Z,long,long,short,short,none
1,short,long,long,long,long
2,short,short,long,long,long
3,short,short,short,long,long
4,short,short,short,short,long
5,short,short,short,short,short
6,long,short,short,short,short
7,long,long,short,short,short
8,long,long,long,short,short
9,long,long,long,long,short
0,long,long,long,long,long
```

Comment: I'm curious about what `Morse.csv` looks like, is there any way you could add it to your question (separate code section?) or paste it to something like [bpaste](https://bpaste.net/) and add a link to it?

Comment: Sure! I have added another code section that contains the csv.

Comment: Thanks for adding it! I'm curious about a couple more things, 1) is the csv file mandatory? 2) if it is mandatory, can the structure can be changed at all? The reason I ask is it might be much simpler to just use a dictionary with the key/value pairs for the morse code.

Comment: I think it is not mandatory. I wanted to apply what I have learned and kind of "pretended" that I have a pre set csv that I have to manipulate with my code in order to reach my goal. I think it was partly due to the fact that I did a tutorial about reading a csv right before. Regarding the dictionary: I will definitely give it a try!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm aware that you are a beginner. So I will try to improve your code starting from the most obvious problems and try advance step by step.

## Variable names

Names like `x, y, z` are an absolute no-go (unless naming coordinates). This is like naming them `guesswhat`. Names should describe what the variable holds as close to natural language as possible. So legal names for `x, y, z` would be `long, short, none`. Aloso other names are far from perfect. `for SingLetter in LetterInput:` should read `for letter in message:`. You generate a lot of temporary variables which requires you to invent a lot of names. Try avoid some temporaries and/or name temporaries 'less important' than variables you want to use later on. `SingLetUp = SingLetter.upper()` could read `letter = letter.upper()`. When reading `SingLetUp` I do think of 'singing', 'letting' and 'up'. There is no need to save letters in names, if a long name is needed, let it be. But a letter is always a single one, a group of letters shall be named 'word' or 'message' anyway.

## Temporaries

As already said, you tend to use too many of them. one case where it makes the code bloated and thus less readable is

```
x = 'short'
y = 'long'
z = 'none'
```

and the only later use

```
if sing == x:
```

this useless. if named correctly this would read

```
short = 'short'
# ...
if symbol == short:
```

which shows the redundancy. it could simply read

```
if symbol == 'short':
```

saving some lines without any negative implications.

## Do not repeat yourself

This is one of the most important rules to consider. In

```
if sing == x:
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)

if sing == y:
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

you have two code blocks differing by just one value. all the other parts are required(!) to be identical. this is asking for a function definition (I'm not sure if you already learned that). We do something like (still not perfect)

```
def gpio_out(length):
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(length)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

and use it like

```
if symbol == 'short':
    gpio_out(0.2)

if symbol == 'long':
    gpio_out(1)
```

## Do not use 'magic values' in the code but define named constants

The most obvious use cases is to change the GPIO pin. The value `18` is appearing 7 times in your source and must be maintained to match. forgetting to change one will lead to subtle errors. So we do

```
morse_gpio = 18
```

and use this name throughout the code. the same applies to all other constants, especially the time values.

## About morse code and your implementation

the most frequent letters in western languages are 'e', 't', 'n', ... that is why Morse assigned short codes to these letters. you are outputting many 'none' instead of a single pause separating letters. we fix this by not outputting anything on `'none'` but inserting a single pause.

```
for symbol in pos:
    if symbol == 'short':
        gpio_out(0.2)
    if symbol == 'long':
        gpio_out(1)
    if symbol == 'none':
        pass
time.sleep(1)
```

## Reading the csv file

While this might have been part of your assignment - csv is a little heavy here. this is implicitely shown in your code as you never use the header names. Another hint is that you have to use fill values of `none`. However you could read such a simple file in python directly. Also we get rid of this superfluous `'none'` immediately. Nowhere in the code we are expecting a fixed length code, quite contrary we have special handling for it.

```
letters = []    #a new list with letters only
codes = []      #a new list with morse code only
with open('Morse.csv') as codefile:
    next(codefile)  #jump over the column description line and an empty line
    next(codefile)
    for line in codefile:
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        letters.append(words[0])    # append letter
        code = [x for x in words[1:] if x != 'none']
        codes.append(code)          # append effective code only
```

here i used list [comprehension https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions]

## Use the right data structures

If you want to look up code for a letter you want to write `code = codes[letter]` which is clean and readable. so we use a dict for storing our codes

```
codes = dict()
with open('Morse.csv') as codefile:
    next(codefile)  #jump over the column description line and an empty line
    next(codefile)
    for line in codefile:
        words = line.strip().split(',')
        code = [x for x in words[1:] if x != 'none']
        codes[words[0]] = code          # append effective code only
```

and rewrite the access

```
MorseCode = [] #a new list where the final code for the LED input is saved

for SingLetter in LetterInput: #iterate through the input

    SingLetUp = SingLetter.upper() #capitalize letters so they can be found in csv

    if SingLetUp not in letters: #jump over spaces and special characters 
        continue

    MorseDex = letters.index(SingLetUp) #find code that corresponds with letter by matching indices 
    SingCode = codes[MorseDex]
    MorseCode.append(SingCode) #fill up list
```

to

```
morse_code = [] #a new list where the final code for the LED input is saved

for letter in message.upper(): #iterate through the input

    if letter in codes:     # ignore spaces and special characters 
        morse_code.append(codes[letter])    # fill up list
```

## Structure your code

Avoid so called spaghetti code, that is many lines of code at the same name space. As already stated about your variable names, have good names and make clear what scope they have. when using functions local variables are not visible outside. this improves readability and avoids name collisions. so we define some functions of already identified code blocks

```
def read_codes():
    #[...]
    return codes

def encode(message, codes):
    #[...]
    return code

def output_code(code):
    #[...]
```

and use it them like

```
codes = read_codes()
message = input('what do you want to morse? ')
code = encode(message, codes)
output_code(code)
```

Thas limits visibility of name like `code` or `letter`. also it adds testability. we can now call `encode` from some testcases without needing interactive user input.

## Further down on internal data representation

When doing debugging you most probably do not want to print `[['short', 'long'], ['short'], ['long']]` more likely you want to print `.- . -`. So why not represent the symbols as shorter characters througout the code? We improve our existing function

```
def read_codes():
    codes = dict()
    with open('Morse.csv') as codefile:
        next(codefile)  #jump over the column description line and an empty line
        next(codefile)
        for line in codefile:
            words = line.strip().split(',')
            code = [x for x in words[1:] if x != 'none']
            codes[words[0]] = code          # append effective code only
    return codes
```

to

```
for line in codefile:
    words = line.strip().split(',')
    shortcode = {'long':'-', 'short':'.'}
    code = [shortcode[x] for x in words[1:] if x != 'none']
    codes[words[0]] = ''.join(code)          # append effective code only
```

here we do not only replace longer strings by characters but also join this characters to a string. this string allows better logging. For `print(encode("Hello world!", codes))` we get `['....', '.', '.-..', '.-..', '---', '.--', '---', '.-.', '.-..', '-..']`. Wouldn't it be nice to have `'.... . .-.. .-.. --- .-- --- .-. .-.. -..'` where the blanks represent the pause between letters? this would make the output loop better as it would not do an additional pause at the end. So somewhere in the code we should do `' '.join(code)`, either just before outputting or in encoding. your choice. for debugging I'd prefer to have it in encoding.

```
def encode(message, codes):
    code = []    # a new list where the final code for the LED input is saved
    for letter in message.upper(): #iterate through the input
        if letter in codes: #jump over spaces and special characters 
            code.append(codes[letter]) #fill up list
    return ' '.join(code)
```

of course we now have to fix the output

```
def output_code(code):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

    for symbol in code:
        print(symbol, end='', flush=True) # debug output

        if symbol == '.':
            gpio_out(0.2)
        elif symbol == '-':
            gpio_out(1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Note that we also encapsulated all GPIO stuff in this function. there is no neet to initialize GPIOs before outputting.

## Main guard

In python modules may be run directly or they may be imported by some other module e. g. a unit test. So there is a pattern to avoid hassle on import

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # stuff only executed on direct execution but not on import
```

current state of our module now

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

symbol_long = 1
symbol_short = 0.2
symbol_pause = 0.5
letter_pause = 1
morse_gpio = 18

def read_codes():
    codes = dict()
    with open('Morse.csv') as codefile:
        next(codefile)  #jump over the column description line and an empty line
        next(codefile)
        for line in codefile:
            words = line.strip().split(',')
            shortcode = {'long':'-', 'short':'.'}
            code = [shortcode[x] for x in words[1:] if x != 'none']
            codes[words[0]] = ''.join(code)          # append effective code only
    return codes

def encode(message, codes):
    code = []    # a new list where the final code for the LED input is saved
    for letter in message.upper(): #iterate through the input
        if letter in codes: #jump over spaces and special characters 
            code.append(codes[letter]) #fill up list
    return ' '.join(code) # 

def gpio_out(length):
    GPIO.output(morse_gpio, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(length)
    GPIO.output(morse_gpio, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(symbol_pause)

def output_code(code):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(morse_gpio, GPIO.OUT)
    for symbol in code:
        print(symbol, end='', flush=True) # debug output

        if symbol == '.':
            gpio_out(symbol_short)
        elif symbol == '-':
            gpio_out(symbol_long)
        else:
            time.sleep(letter_pause)
    GPIO.output(morse_gpio, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    codes = read_codes()
    print(codes) # debug output
    message = input('what do you want to morse? ')
    code = encode(message, codes)
    print(code) # debug output
    output_code(code)
```

## Still to do

- Better comments - comment what is not obvious.
- Docstrings - explain what your functions do. Better encapsulation - avoid globals and pass parameters to functions.
- unit testing - worth to look at.

Comment: another thing you can do is using generators and generator expressions . The last 3 lines of `read_codes` would become `code = (shortcode[x] for x in words[1:] if x != 'none'); yield words[0], ''.join(code)`. Convention for global constants as `symbol_long ` is also in `ALL_CAPS`

Comment: @MaartenFabré - you are right. I tried to do the most important points, which took some time, and did not go for PEP 8 fully.

Comment: In your `encode`, by filtering out all other symbols, you also delete the spaces around words [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Representation,_timing,_and_speeds)

Comment: @stefan: Thanks for this elaborate review. A few follow up questions: you say that csv is a bit too much for this assignment. Is there a threshold that tells me "okay, now using csv is the right choice"? Inside the `read_codes` function. Does the `.strip()` have an effect here or is it just for "safety reasons"? Is `codes = dict()` equivalent to `codes = {}`? In the `encode` function, why did you introduce the list `code = []`? wouldn't it be possible to save the line and say `code = codes[letter]` instead of appending it to an empty list?

Comment: csv is fine if you are familiar with it, but it is not necessary. Use csv when you want to read different data files and/or need some of the provided functions or configuration options. the file you read is actually a config file which is in a csv format. your script will never read a different file and you do not save a single line of code by using the csv module. In such cases I recommend to go without extra modules as there may be a another person reading/maintaining the code with little knowledge of this imported module.

Comment: `strip()` removes the linefeed. actually `{}` is more efficient than `dict()`. `encode()` does all letters of your message, the append is the same as in your code with the same comment still. the list `code` is equivalent to your `MorseCode`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing 2 parts that could be improved:

```
for row in readCSV: #fill up the new lists

    letter = row[0]
    code = row

    code.remove(row[0])
```

you could get `letter` and `code` in a single line like this (using star unpacking, Python 3 only):

```
letter,*code = row
```

you could then create a dictionary letter => code (with `letters_dict = {}`) for further use:

```
letters_dict[letter] = code
```

(you can delete `letters` and `codes` lists as the dictionary *is* the database now)

now the letter test is faster (dict search vs list seach):

```
if SingLetUp not in letters_dict: #jump over spaces and special characters 
    continue
```

and that can be replaced by dict lookup as well:

```
MorseDex = letters.index(SingLetUp) #find code that corresponds with letter by matching indices 
SingCode = codes[MorseDex]
```

replaced by

```
SingCode = letters_dict[SingLetUp]
```

(using `index` is slow, using indices is soooo Fortran)

and in the second loop use `elif` to avoid useless testing:

```
    if sing == x:
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        ...
    elif sing == y:
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
    elif sing == z:
        ...
```

Also, variables should respect [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names): `readCSV` should be `read_csv`, `MorseCode` should be `morse_code` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

a slight adaptation of stefan's excellent answer

I would implement the `read_codes` like this, using `csv`, `filter`. And keeping in mind these excellent talks ([1](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python), [2](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/slides/2015-05-pywaw/hoist/)) by Brandon Rhodes about bringing out the IO

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

def read_codes(filehandle, **kwargs):
    content = csv.reader(filehandle, **kwargs)
    for letter, *words in islice(content, 2, None):
        code = filter(lambda x: x != 'none', words)
        yield letter, tuple(code)
```

Then you can also more easily test it with something like this:

```
with StringIO(morse) as filehandle:
    codes = dict(read_codes(filehandle))
```

The `**kwargs` is to pass on parameters of the csv-file like the separator to handle diverging formarts